# How to colorize Django test results in OSX terminal?

Tags: python, django, macos, terminal

I'd like to colorize the Django test outputs  with the nice visual queues of "green=pass, red=failure" font colors in the terminal, similar to what I get with rails/rake (e.g. ....F..FF.... where F is red for failure and the dots are green for passing unit tests).
Anyone know how to do this easily?  Is there a bash_profile or python import or setting?

Answer (score 0):

Django has it [built-in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syntax-coloring).

The colors used for syntax highlighting can be customized. Django ships with three color palettes:

- dark, suited to terminals that show white text on a black background. This is the default palette.
- light, suited to terminals that show black text on a white background.
- nocolor, which disables syntax highlighting.

You select a palette by setting a DJANGO_COLORS environment variable to specify the palette you want to use. For example, to specify the light palette under a Unix or OS/X BASH shell, you would run the following at a command prompt:

```
export DJANGO_COLORS="light"
```

There's also [django-colors-formatter](https://github.com/tiliv/django-colors-formatter) package if you wish more customization:

```
LOGGING = {
    'formatters': {
        'colored': {
            '()': 'djangocolors_formatter.DjangoColorsFormatter',
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(module)s %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'colored',
    },
    'loggers': 
        'myproject': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Artur.  So if I'm in the OSX terminal, and do:

$> export DJANGO_COLORS="error=yellow/blue,blink;notice=magenta"

And then run my failing test:
$> python3 manage.py test polls

I assume I should see a flashing blue/yellow "E" in the output:
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
..E.....

Right?  But I don't (yet).